# Link search results with posts in Laravel

Tags: laravel, search, laravel-8

I've been searching for two weeks for how to create a search for images in laravel. Now it's a working search, but the problem is the results are not linked to the Post. I need help with this, please. I don't know anything about programming, and I follow some answers online to solve the problem.

**SearchController**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    function search(Request $request)
    {
        if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
            $search_text = $_GET['query'];
            $image_uploads = DB::table('image_uploads')
                ->where('filename', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_text.'%')
                ->paginate(50);
            return view('search', ['image_uploads' => $image_uploads]);
        } else {
            return view('search');
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Blade**

```
@if(isset($image_uploads))
@if(count($image_uploads) > 0)
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-large-top uk-margin-large-bottom">
    <div class="uk-grid">
        <div id="tm-right-section" class="uk-width-large-1-1 uk-width-medium-7-10"
             data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-fade', target:'img'}">
            <div class="uk-grid-width-small-1-3 uk-grid-width-medium-1-4 
            uk-grid-width-large-1-10"
                 data-uk-grid="{gutter: 20}">
                @foreach($image_uploads as $image_uploads)
                <div>
                    <div class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover">
                        <img src="{{ URL ($image_uploads->filename) }}">
                        <div class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-fade uk-overlay-background 
                        uk-overlay-icon"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        @else
        <tr>
            <td>No Results found!!! Please try Again</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

**Download Blade**

```
@foreach($Downloads as $Download)
    @if(isset($Download->ImageUpload->filename))
        <img src="{!! asset($Download->ImageUpload->filename) !!}" 
             alt="Image Download">
    @else
    @endif
    <a href="{!! url('Downloads') !!}/{!! $Download->slug !!}"></a>
@endforeach
<div class="uk-margin-large-top uk-margin-bottom pagination">
    {!! $Downloads->links() !!}
</div>
```

And finally, this is the link for my site.
[Iconaty.com/search](http://iconaty.com/en/search)

Answer (score 0):

You have done a great job. I think the issue with the controller try it out this

```
function search(Request $request){
            
            if($request->has('query') && $request->query!='' ){
                
       $search_text =$request->query;
                $image_uploads = DB::table('image_uploads')->where('filename','LIKE','%'.$search_text.'%')->paginate(50);
            return view('search',['image_uploads'=>$image_uploads]);
            }else{
            return view('search');
        }
```

I hope its work for you.... If its not working...  Try to figure out does the query gives the value like this...

```
function search(Request $request){
            
            if($request->has('query') && $request->query!='' ){
                
       $search_text = $request->query;
                $image_uploads = DB::table('image_uploads')->where('filename','LIKE','%'.$search_text.'%')->paginate(50);

 dd($image_uploads);
            return view('search',['image_uploads'=>$image_uploads]);
            }else{
           dd($image_uploads);
            return view('search');
        }
```

Try this out to figure out your issue

Comment: did'nt work, bring me this message:
(Error
Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag could not be converted to string
)

Comment: Can you share the project git repo or else we can connect on any desk or else ping me on WhatsApp 7708454539